# regsrv32: Do I need to unregister a COM object before registering its update?

Tags: com

I release every now and then updates of COM objects which I have registered on client machines.

**Noob question about the registry:**

Everytime I register those updates, with the same namespace and object names, under a new random GUID, what is happening ? Are the objects substituted ? Are the previous objects versions still there ? Do I need to unregister the previous versions ? Is it possible to unregister raw GUIDs ?

Comment: The word GUID is often terribly misused. GUID is a data type and conveys no meaning. Are you talking about CLSID? LIBID? One or more Interface IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration you need depends on the approach you choose to update your COM objects. The easiest is to update existing object, in which case you retain CLSIDs and objects intact, possibly extending with new methods and interfaces. In this case you basically don't need to unregister, however you can run into scenarios where you are retiring certain COM class and without unregistering it you would leave its registration on registry as orphaned junk.

It is safer to unregister the module being replaced, and then register the new one after it is installed. Alternatively, your new COM library can take care of upgrades internally and explicitly remove retired registrations (it is just more complicated and often unnecessary compared to plain unregistering older version). Unregister/re-register cycle might remove some persistent states if you have any and unregistration cleans them up.

You might want to prefer another apoproach if you want your versions run side by side in target system. In this case you would use new CLSIDs for all/some classes, distinct (esp. versioned) ProgIDs, and version independent ProgID for the applications to bind to "current" or installed latest version of your class.

Comment: I thought registering a COM object update under the same GUID was bad. DLL hell ?

Comment: what are the different options/commands to unregister COM objects ?

Comment: It is not bad. You are upgrading backend transparently to everyone using your COM class.